# Java UDP receive()

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I am trying to implement Go Back N using UDP sockets in Java. I have a sender and receiver thread at the client end. The sender thread has its own UPD socket to send the data packets and the receiver thread has its own port to receive acknowledgements. If a receiver doesn't receive ACK before a timeout period, the packet has to be retransmitted. Both threads are always running with a `while(true)` loop. I observe that when there are no packet losses(i.e no timeouts), this functionality of sending and receiving works fine, but when the ACK isn't received, that is when there is a timeout, the switching to the sender thread (for retransmission) isn't happening. The execution is stuck in the receiver's for loop, showing timeouts over and over again.
I even tried using `Thread.Sleep()`, so that it lets the other thread work. but it isn't happening. Any help would be appreciated.

(The slideflag that is set to 0, will initiate retransmission in the other thread ideally)

```
while(true){
    socket.setSoTimeout(10000);
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];        
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
    try{
        socket.receive(packet);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Socket timeout!");
        ClientMain.setslideFlag(0);

        Thread.sleep(10000);
        continue;   
    }
}
```

Comment: Er... something is a little off here. If both the "sender" and "receiver" are at the "client" end... what is at the server end?

Comment: Sender thread and receiver thread I meant. Sender thread to send Packets to server. Receiver thread to receive ACKs from Server.

Comment: So, I repeat my question: what is at the server end?

Comment: AFAIR UDP never had ACK signal, for a simple reason that it (UDP) is designed as unidirectional message transmission protocol. The message/packet may never arrive at the receiver end because it is NOT guaranteed to do so. If messages are sent @ 10 seconds intervals you should in reality have NO time-out on receiver socket at all.

Comment: How do you expect the sender to distinguish if the receiver got the message or if the message was lost?